# Paypal is not showing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, paypal

I have installed two payment gateways on magento 2. Ccavenue payment gateway for India and PayPal for other countries. When we enter the PIN code of India, the payment gateway (Ccavenue payment gateway) is displayed. But when you enter the PIN code of any country outside, then Paypal is not visible. But after refreshing the page, Paypal appears[image]

Before Refresh
After Refresh
[image]

error Showing in console 
Uncaught TypeError: items is not a function at collection.js:276 at Function..each..forEach (underscore.js:150) at UiClass._updateCollection (collection.js:275) at UiClass.removeChild (collection.js:129) at UiClass. (element.js:547) at Array.forEach () at UiClass._clearRefs (element.js:546) at UiClass.destroy (element.js:514) at UiClass._super (wrapper.js:106) at UiClass.destroy (collection.js:235) at UiClass.destroy (wrapper.js:109) at iterator (observable_array.js:24) at underscore.js:73 at Function..each..forEach (underscore.js:145) at Function.each (observable_array.js:50) at UiClass.destroy (collection.js:237)

Comment: any errors in console or error log?

Comment: @MagenX can't post error in the comment box that's replyed in new ans please check this